# Multiple str edits to a single .txt file python

Tags: python, string, text, data-manipulation

I've scraped some comments from a webpage using selenium and saved them to a text file. Now I would like to perform multiple edits to the text file and save it again. I've tried to group the following into one smooth flow but I'm fairly new to python so I just couldn't get it right. Examples of what happened to me at the bottom. The only way I could get it to work is to open and close the file over and over.

These are the action I want to perform in the order the need to:

```
with open('results.txt', 'r') as f:

    lines = f.readlines()
with open("results.txt", "w") as f:

    for line in lines:
        f.write(line.replace("a sample text line", ' '))

with open('results.txt', 'r') as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

with open("results.txt", "w") as f:

    pattern = r'\d in \d example text'
    for line in lines:
        f.write(re.sub(pattern, "", line))

with open('results.txt', 'r') as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

with open('results.txt','w') as file:

    for line in lines:
        if not line.isspace():
            file.write(line)

with open('results.txt', 'r') as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

with open("results.txt", "w") as f:

    for line in lines:
        f.write(line.replace(" ", '-'))
```

I've tried to loop them into one but I get doubled lines, words, or extra spaces.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Would you be able share how the input file looks like and how the expected output file should look like, to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do these in one smooth pass, you better open another file to write the desired results i.e.

```
import re
pattern = r"\d in \d example text"

# Open your results file for reading and another one for writing
with open("results.txt", "r") as fh_in, open("output.txt", "w") as fh_out:
    for line in fh_in:
        # Process the line
        line = line.replace("a sample text line", " ")
        line = re.sub(pattern, "", line)
        if line.isspace():
            continue
        line = line.replace(" ", "-")
        # Write out
        fh_out.write(line)
```

We process each line in order you described and the resultant line goes to output file.

Comment: Great, this worked thanks, I'll keep that in mind anytime I need to make changes like that!